# Apache ignite json field

Tags: ignite

Perhaps I am missing this in the documentation, but is it possible to store and query against json data in Apache Ignite? For example, let's say I have a "table" called "cars" with the following fields:

```
model
blueprint
```

The "blueprint" field is actually a json field that may contain data such as:

```
{
    horsepower: 200,
    mpg: 30
}
```

Those are not the only fields for the "blueprint" field, and it may contain many more or less fields. Is it possible to run a query such as:

```
SELECT model FROM cars WHERE blueprint.horsepower < 300 AND blueprint.mpg > 20
```

It is not known in advance what the fields will be for the "blueprint" field, and creating indexes for them is not optional.

Note: This is not a conversation about if this is the logically optimal way to store this information, or how the "blueprint" field should be stored in a separate table. This question is meant to understand if querying against a json field is trivially possible in apache ignite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported out of the box as for now. However, you can create conversion logic between JSON and Ignite binary format and save `BinaryObject`s in caches. To create a `BinaryObject` without a Java class, you can use binary object builder: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller#modifying-binary-objects-using-binaryobjectbuilder